# Why is Next.js middleware running multiple times?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js

I created a fresh [Next.js](https://nextjs.org/docs/getting-started) using `npx create-next-app@latest --typescript`. After installation (the version being `13.3.4`), without changing any files, I added a new `middleware.ts` file inside the `src` folder, and I only put this block of code:

```
import type { NextRequest } from "next/server";
import { NextResponse } from "next/server";

export function middleware(request: NextRequest) {
  console.log("request", JSON.stringify(request));
  return NextResponse.next();
}
```

The console log is hit multiple times. I think it should be once, right? Is there any configuration I need to do for this fresh  Next.js installation?

Note: I am going to do some cookie logic here in the [middleware](https://nextjs.org/docs/advanced-features/middleware) for authentication. Screenshot:

[image]

Comment: You may check this issue:
https://github.com/vercel/next.js/issues/38267

Comment: @jyangca yes I've read it, it is not resolved.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This is normal because a `middleware` by default runs for every request, including the ones for getting assets like JavaScritp, CSS, and image files.  As you can read on the [doc](https://nextjs.org/docs/advanced-features/middleware#matching-paths):

> Middleware will be invoked for **every route in your project**. The following is the execution order:
>
> 1. `headers` from `next.config.js`
> 2. `redirects` from `next.config.js`
> 3. Middleware (`rewrites`, `redirects`, etc.)
> 4. `beforeFiles` (`rewrites`) from `next.config.js`
> 5. Filesystem routes (`public/`, `_next/static/`, `pages`, etc.)
> 6. `afterFiles` (`rewrites`) from `next.config.js`
> 7. Dynamic Routes (`/blog/[slug]`)
> 8. `fallback` (`rewrites`) from `next.config.js`

If you add a `console.log(request.nextUrl.pathname)`, you would see the different paths for which it's running. To have it execute for some paths only, you need to use [conditional statements](https://nextjs.org/docs/advanced-features/middleware#conditional-statements) or the [`matcher`](https://nextjs.org/docs/advanced-features/middleware#matcher) config, like so:

```typescript
// middleware.ts

import type { NextRequest } from "next/server";
import { NextResponse } from "next/server";

export function middleware(request: NextRequest) {
  console.log("Request for : ", request.nextUrl.pathname);
  return NextResponse.next();
}

export const config = {
  // The above middleware would only run for the "/" path
  matcher: '/',
}
```

Another matching pattern that's used a lot is this one:

```typescript
// middleware.ts

import type { NextRequest } from "next/server";
import { NextResponse } from "next/server";

export function middleware(request: NextRequest) {
  console.log("Request for : ", request.nextUrl.pathname);
  return NextResponse.next();
}

export const config = {
  matcher: [
    /*
     * Match all request paths except for the ones starting with:
     * - api (API routes)
     * - _next/static (static files)
     * - _next/image (image optimization files)
     * - favicon.ico (favicon file)
     */
    '/((?!api|_next/static|_next/image|favicon.ico).*)',
  ],
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Here, using Next `14.0.3`, I have duplicate requests in middleware for the same pathname using a simple matcher:

```
export const config = {
  // Skip all paths that should not be internationalized
  matcher: ['/((?!api|_next|_vercel|.*\\..*).*)'],
}
```

Seems to be a real bug: https://github.com/vercel/next.js/issues/39917